# changing the pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

While writing my code I came upon a problem

```
char* a = malloc (sizeof(char));
a = "blabla";
free(a);
```

gives me an error, because I changed the value of the pointer a to something else.

So, why does this work

```
char* a = "blabla";
printf("%s", a);
```

again I'm changing  the value of the pointer to `blabla`, I'm ruining the pointers address. It should be error, shouldn't it?

Comment: No you are not changing the value of the pointer in the second snippet. You initialise it with a value. Thats some difference regarding to the first example.

Comment: When using string literals, the compiler will give you a *pointer* to a read-only array. What makes you think that assigning this pointer to a variable declared as a pointer, to "ruin" the variable?

Comment: The cause of the error in the first snippet is not that you changed the value of `a`, but what you changed it to. If you add `free(a)` at the end of the second you will experience exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second one you are creating a pointer to the string literal `"blabla"`, it doesn't affect the pointer in any way, a new pointer is created. In the first example you change the value of the pointer itself.

Comment: That's no why the code crashes. The reason the first example crashes is that you pass to `free()` a pointer that has not been acquired though `malloc()`.

Comment: The asker knows why the `free()` gives an error; they said "because I changed the value of the pointer a to something else" within the question. I interpreted the question as, "Why does example 2 work?", which is what I answered.

Comment: But changing the pointer value to something else is not a problem *per-se,* the problem is changing the pointer value to a value that is neither the `NULL` pointer nor was returned by `malloc()`.

Answer (score 4):

The first case has a bug because you are passing an address to `free` other than one you got from `malloc`. That is an error.

The second case has no such problem, so why shouldn't it work? You aren't "ruining" the pointer's address, you are setting it to a valid address and then using that valid address for a valid purpose.

The second example is no different from:

```
int i = 1;
printf ("%d", i);
```

You set its value and used the new legal value in a proper way, so no problem.

Comment: I'd complement the answer saying that even though in the second case you got a valid pointer, you are not allowed to release the memory with free -- because, you know, it is a constant string.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet causes memory leak. Once the statement `a = "blabla";` is executed, the pointer `a` will no longer point to the memory allocated by `malloc` and its address gets lost.

Answer (score -1):

The first snippet where your address gets lost where 'blaba' is stored It will give error.In the second one you assinged directly the value to blabla